# How do vector graphics engines (like adobe illustrator) render lines of prescribed thicknesses?

Tags: vectors, desmos

I know that vector graphics engines use mathematical formulas to render figures. Suppose I have a curve, which I created using the pen tool on adobe illustrator. I know that the engine is doing something in the background with bezier curves to convert the anchor points and handles into the curve.

Now i use the options available to set a thickness for the path - something like 5 px. A region around the curve is filled with a colour. How does the engine know which region to colour?

I’m really curious about the mathematics behind vector graphics engines. Please do share any references (documentation maybe) that helps understand it, even if it isn’t helpful for answering this particular question. Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's essentially a quadratic root problem. The computer checks which points are within a given distance from the curve, which is solving a degree 2 polynomial.

Comment: @Community To me, the question seems pretty clear and specific. Can you specify what is ambiguous exactly?

Comment: @William Could you explain this more elaborately in an answer?

Comment: Suppose you have a point $y$, and you wish to know if you want to color it. This amounts to determining if $d(x,y) < r$ for some number $r$, for any point $x$ on the curve. That is to say--- is there a solution $x$ on the curve that satisfies the equation $(x_1 - y_1)^2 + (x_2 - y_2)^2 < r^2$?

Comment: Deciding whether a point lies within a given distance from a cubic curve is pretty complicated. It's certainly harder than just solving a quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly just semi-educated guessing ... I don't work for Adobe.

As you say, the control points are used to construct cubic Bezier curves. Then, what happens next (I suspect) is that the Bezier curves are approximated by strings of straight lines, and some pretty low level graphics code draws the straight lines. Drawing straight lines (even fat anti-aliased ones) is a well understood problem. The basic classic line-drawing algorithm is Bresenham's. The modern standard is [Xiaolin Wu's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm).

Comment: While this does make some sense, I’m not entirely convinced. Can’t pinpoint why - just a gut feeling. Thanks for the answer though!